# Allow Restkit to send NULL value for object

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I am trying to get RestKit to send an empty value for field in an object I am `PATCH`ing to a server.

I have an object that I send up and I change the `assigned_to_id` in the request

```
{"request":{"title":"Asdad", "status":"open", "assigned_to_id": 4}}
```

`request` is an `NSManagedObject` and `assigned_to_id` is a `NSNumber`

However, when I want to unassign the request, I perform:

```
request.assigned_to_id = [NSNull NULL];
```

But then RestKit sends the request as:

```
{"request":{"title":"Asdad", "status":"open"}}
```

It doesn't include the assigned_to_id since it's value is NULL. Is there a way to prevent this? I'd like for it to send:

```
{"request":{"title":"Asdad", "status":"open", "assigned_to_id": null }}
```

**=== UPDATE ===**

After doing some preliminary research, I've seen that you can use `setDefaultValueForMissingAttributes` but it doesn't seem like that is helping, since it's still not sending correctly.

```
RKObjectMapping *updateMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
updateMapping.setDefaultValueForMissingAttributes = YES;
updateMapping.setNilForMissingRelationships = YES;
[updateMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"title", @"assigned_to_id", @"status"]];
```

Comment: Well sure you can download source code and change the behaviour there, or you can use a separate NSString property, I would guess that RestKit is using the getters so you can try to implement your own getter for NSString property that would check NSNumber value and return either an empty string or a textual representation of the number.

Comment: Do you control the server? Because you should really use a `DELETE` request to handle this...

Comment: @Wain I do control the server, but I don't think a `DELETE` request is necessary here. The data for the user and the request *is* stored in a bridge table, however, when someone updates a request, instead of having to make two requests (one to update the request, one to possibly delete the assignee) it makes more sense to make one request where you just turn the assignee to `NULL` and Rails handles that logic for ya. I'm gonna post (below) what I resolved to doing for now, even though I don't think it's the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is the best solution, but...

The `assigned_to_id` default value is 0, so when if the request becomes unassigned, I send up the following `PATCH` request:

```
{"request":{"title":"Asdad", "status":"open", "assigned_to_id": 0 }}
```

and then I use the API logic to make the request unassigned.

If anyone figures out how to send the RestKit request with a parameter that is `NULL` let me know!